# GLIBC 2.14 is missing

Tags: glibc

I recently migrated from Windows 7 to RHEL 6.7 on my laptop (ThinkPad 430). While I was trying to install a diff merge software it complained that **libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by diffmerge-3.3.2.1139-1.x86_64**.

I checked the lib64 folder of my system and I found that libc.so.6 is a softlink to the libc-2.12.so share object file ?

Please provide some help here as I am novice to linux..

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You have glibc 2.12, the package requires ≥ 2.14.  Basically, RHEL 6 is too old.

According to http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/downloads.php it requires Fedora 17; RHEL 6 was forked from Fedora 12.  RHEL 7 was forked from Fedora 19, upgrading to that should do the trick.

What you're doing is a bit like trying to install software which only works with Windows 8+ on Windows 7… the timelines even match pretty well; Fedora 12 and Windows 7 were released in 2009, Fedora 19 and Windows 8 were released in 2013 and 2012, respectively.

Comment: So instead of upgrading, if I try to copy the library >= 2.14 and make the symbolic link libc.so.6 point to the newly copied .so (shared object) library, will that do ?

Comment: No, You shouldn't just copy around libraries on any platform. If you want to stick with RHEL upgrade to 7, not sure why you want RHEL on a laptop in the first place though.